# PC Fans Stay on After Shutting Down

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I am interested in cloning my PC's HDD to an SSD using CloneZilla, and then using my HDD to store data. Because my SSD is smaller than my HDD, I had to use GParted to shrink the parition down before copying, but before doing that, I made a  CloneZilla backup image to my NAS drive. While in the process of cloning from the HDD to the SSD, I had to have a power failure because things were just going too well. Because I did not want to risk an issue with either disk, I decided to wipe both of them, and restore my CloneZilla backup to my HDD and try again. As part of what I need to do before I clone the shrunken partition to the SSD, I needed to boot in to Windows and run a disk check, and this is where the problem that this post is about comes in to play: every time I shut down the computer down after having it booted in to Windows, the power button on the front stays on, and the fans in the machine continue to spin, but everything else stops. Even the HDD spins down.

I have read that this can either be a hardware or software issue, but I am convinced that it is software-based because of two reasons. First, the machine is new, so there should be nothing failing on it yet. Second, whenever I boot the machine to Linux from a flash drive, everything shuts off with no problem.

What is the matter here? I am using Windows 10 Pro x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by going to my computer manufacturer's website and reflashing the latest BIOS update. I say "reflashing" because when I purchased the computer about a month ago, flashing the latest BIOS update was the first thing that I did. There has not been a new update released since then, so I haven't really upgraded it, but rather, reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no bios update:

1) Disable fast startup (in Power Options)

But that didn't fix it for me, yet:

2) Disable "Intel(R) Management Engine Interface" from Device Manager (below "System devices")

did fix the problem for me.

Comment: I actually tried this as well, but it didn't work for me.